# International Student applying for a PhD in a university in Taiwan

Tags: phd, computer-science, international-students, work-life-balance, south-east-asia

I am a student doing my Masters in India, and was considering doing a PhD (in computer science, specifically ML) in a university in Taipei, Taiwan. I went to their website, but couldn't find some of the details I was looking for. These were the questions (in no particular order)

1. Will language be an issue? Are we expected to learn Chinese? The website said that there are courses in Chinese and English, but nothing more. I wanted to know in terms of doing courses, communicating with the advisor and his other students, as well as writing papers.
2. What about food? I am a vegetarian.
3. Can i get scholarship there? From the govt or TAship/RAship?
4. What about the coursework which I will have to do in my PhD? How long would it take(duration)? And how is the workload?

Comment: And there was I thinking the Chinese were pretty good with vegetarian cuisine...

Comment: I took the liberty to edit out the name of the university because we do not take questions for a specific university. (The question is probably going to be closed because it's too specific.)

Comment: I had asked a question related to master's coursework in the US previously, and that was closed because it was too broad, and the details vary from university to university. So I thought I would look at them individually and then ask doubts pertaining to that specific university (which I cannot find on the internet). But now I'm confused, what exactly should be the scope of the question?

Answer (score 3):

1. I know there are many international PhD students there. I think you need not to worry about English use in the classrooms. However, you will need to learn Chinese to some extent in order to live in Taiwan. Not knowing the local language would cause you a lot trouble.
2. There are quite a few vegetarian food only restaurants available in Taipei. But, they are not cheap and may be some distance away from university campus.

Talk to the university about 3 & 4.

(I am local in Taipei)

Answer (score 3):

For 2, Vegetarian is quite common in Taiwan since there are significant  Buddhism  population (around 10% ?) there. You should able to find a greater variety of budget choices with a little effort.